# Select a row with containing two different td text

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to select the row below(4th row) which has td text ="scheduled" and td text="QA TEST CHIRAG"

[image]

This is what I have so far, this select the row which has the text QA TEST CHIRAG and click on the adjacent open button:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr/td[text()='QA TEST CHIRAG']/./../td/input[@type='Button' and @value = 'Open']").click()
```

i would like to know how i can check the row with both text scheduled and QA TEST CHIRAG and then click on the open button

Comment: `//tr[td[text()='QA TEST CHIRAG'] and td[text() ="Scheduled"]]/td/input[@type='Button' and @value = 'Open']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote an xpath that says this.

```
find an element whose text="QA TEST CHIRAG" > find a sibling td> 
select input elment inside it.
```

you can extend this with something that says.

```
Select td with text=Scheduled > find sibling element with text="QA TEST CHIRAG" > find sibling td > select input element inside it.
```

in other words you can try this xpath:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr/td[text()='Scheduled']/./../td[text()='QA TEST CHIRAG']/./../td/input[@type='Button' and @value = 'Open']").click()
```